# How to create dynamic array using existing array

Tags: php, arrays

I have on array of data in below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rating] => 4
                    [review] => nice
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [rating] => 2
                    [review] => good
                )
        )

)
```

We customize above array and need to my custom array .
Need out put like below array. array always need 5 to 1 key because i am using this array for rating & review functionality.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [rating] => 0
                    [review] => ""
                )
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [rating] => 4
                    [review] => nice
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [rating] => 0
                    [review] => ""
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [rating] => 2
                    [review] => "good"
                )        

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [rating] => 0
                    [review] => ""
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, you are starting with the array in your first snippet. And you want to convert it into a similar format as the second one? Sorry, your grammar is kind of throwing me off.

Comment: see my question my current array1 & we need array2 as per mention above and my index same as rating value.

Comment: I getting answer. please find below solution as per output.

$arr1 = array(array("rating"=>4,"review"=>"nice"),array("rating"=>2,"review"=>"good"));


$final =array();

 
  
  for($i=5;$i>=1;$i--){
      
      foreach($arr1 as $key =>$val){
      
      
      if($val['rating']==$i)
            {
              $final[$i] = array("rating"=>$val['rating'],"review"=>$val['review']); 
              break;
            }
      else{
              $final[$i] = array("rating"=>0,"review"=>""); 
            }
    }

}

  echo "<pre>"; print_r($final);

Answer (score 1):

I managed to self-solve. Please find below solution as per output.

```
$arr1 = array(array("rating"=>4,"review"=>"nice"),array("rating"=>2,"review"=>"good"));
$final =a rray();
for ($i=5; $i>=1; $i--) {   
    foreach ($arr1 as $key =>$val) {
        if ($val['rating']==$i) {
            $final[$i] = array("rating"=>$val['rating'],"review"=>$val['review']); 
            break;
        } else {
            $final[$i] = array("rating"=>0,"review"=>""); 
        }
    }
}
print_r($final);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Iterate each top level array (if you *don't* have multiple top level arrays, then you should consider restructuring your array structure to be more concise)
- call `array_column()` on the level2 array so that the `rating` values are assigned as keys for their respective subarray.
- Iterate in descending order from 5 to 1 while conditionally saving data to the output array.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/986dd6ebdc2b54b1fd81f53862bd7d91e749a109))

```
$input = [
    [
        ['rating' => 4, 'review' => 'nice'],
        ['rating' => 2, 'review' => 'good']
    ]
];

foreach ($input as $x => $level2) {
    $keyed = array_column($level2, null, 'rating');  // setup more efficient lookup
    for($i = 5 ; $i > 0 ; --$i) {
        $result[$x][$i] = isset($keyed[$i]) ? $keyed[$i] : ['rating' => 0, 'review' => ''];
    }
}
var_export($result);
// output is as desired
```

Comment: Writing `foreach()` then `array_column()` then `for()` means my code only iterates the `for()` once for your sample input array (5 iterations for the sample input).  By writing `for()` first, not using `array_column()`, then `foreach(), there are 21 required iterations for the sample data.